# .NET Runtime Path of Other Win32 Services?

Tags: service

```
var machineservices = ServiceController.GetServices( Environment.MachineName ).ToList();
```

I am able to enumerate the Windows Services installed with that code. However, I need to get the full executable path of each Service, and cannot seem to find the "Path" property. Can anyone clue me in?

Using C#, .NET 4.5.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceController does not provide that information directly. To access that you need to use the registry or preferably WMI using a ManagementObjectSearcher selecting for Win32_Service entities.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection) {
    string pathName = obj["PathName"] as string;
}
```